How to make scrollable list of panels?
new to JavaFX and I'm using SceneBuilder to make a scrollingframe with a VBox inside which has infinite VBoxes inside (user can create them).
The problem is my setup doesnt work. Im using an AnchorPane with a ScrollingPane inside. The rest with this code:
public class ManagerSceneController {

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane ScrollingContainer;
    
   public void initialize() {
       FillScrollPane();
   }
    
    public void FillScrollPane() {
        System.out.println("Führe aus");
        VBox cardContainer = new VBox(10);
        cardContainer.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) { // TO DO: Replace with actual loading
            VBox card = CardComponent.createCard("Webseite"+i, "Username"+i, "Password"+i);
            cardContainer.getChildren().add(card);
            
            System.out.println(card);
            System.out.println("Number of children in cardContainer: " + cardContainer.getChildren().size());
            ScrollingContainer.setFitToWidth(true);
            ScrollingContainer.setFitToHeight(true);
            System.out.println("Erfolgreich ausgeführt");
        }
    }

}

The prints all print and it looks normal but the scrollingPane is just empty.
Card class:
public class CardComponent {
public static VBox createCard(String website, String username, String password) {
    Label websiteLabel = new Label("Website: ");
    Label usernameLabel = new Label("Username: ");
    Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password: ");
    
    VBox card = new VBox(10);
    card.getChildren().addAll(websiteLabel, usernameLabel, passwordLabel);
    card.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    card.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1px;");
    
    
    
    return card;
}
}

I was expecting the scrollingPane to be filled with cards with 3 labels each and some padding in between.
One thing I noticed is that the empty scrollPane doesnt have any scrollbars, not sure if thats normal.

Did you forget scrollingContainer.setContent(cardContainer)?

You should also consider using a ListView here.

whats the benefit of a ListView here?

Thank you so much, that was it lol. Works like a charm.

This looks like a job for a ListView, as stated earlier.

@ByGoalZ "whats the benefit of a ListView here" -- The ListView control is "virtualized". That means it only ever has enough cells to fill its viewport and reuses cells as the user scrolls. The primary benefit of this is that the ListView can display hundreds, thousands, or even millions of items without overwhelming the rendering system (i.e., without causing lag). Plus, ListView comes with built-in scrolling functionality. If your goal is to display an arbitrary number of items in a list format, then you should probably be using a ListView.

Note you can subclass ListCell to customize the UI of each item. You would use your cell implementation by setting the cellFactory of the list view. SedJ601's answer shows an example of this.

I think this is a good case to use ListView. Create a view. In this case, that is CardView. Create a model for the view. In this case, that is CardModel.
Main
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.print.PageLayout;
import javafx.print.PageOrientation;
import javafx.print.Paper;
import javafx.print.Printer;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {    
        ObservableList<CardModel> modelList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            modelList.add(new CardModel(Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
        }
        
        ListView<CardModel> listView = new ListView();
        listView.setItems(modelList);
        listView.setCellFactory((ListView<CardModel> param) -> {
            ListCell<CardModel> cell = new ListCell<CardModel>() {
                CardView cardView = new CardView();
                
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(CardModel item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null) {
                       
                        cardView.setWebsiteText(item.getWebsite());
                        cardView.setUsernameText(item.getUsername());
                        cardView.setPasswordText(item.getPassword());
                        setGraphic(cardView);
                    } else {
                        setText("");
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        });
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane(listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX App");
        primaryStage.show();
    }   
}

CardView
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
final public class CardView extends VBox
{   
    static private final AtomicLong ID_GENERATOR = new AtomicLong(0);
    
    private final LongProperty id = new SimpleLongProperty();
    private final Label lblWebsite = new Label();
    private final Label lblUsername = new Label();
    private final Label lblPassword = new Label();
    
    public CardView()
    {
        id.setValue(ID_GENERATOR.incrementAndGet());
        
        this.getChildren().addAll(lblWebsite, lblUsername, lblPassword);
         this.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1px;");
    }
    
    public CardView(String website, String username, String password)
    {
        id.setValue(ID_GENERATOR.incrementAndGet());
        
        lblWebsite.setText("Website: " + website);
        lblUsername.setText("Username: " + username);
        lblPassword.setText("Password: " + password);
        
        this.getChildren().addAll(lblWebsite, lblUsername, lblPassword);
        this.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1px;");
    }
    
    public Long getCardId()
    {
        return id.getValue();
    }
    
    public String getWebsiteText()
    {
        return lblWebsite.getText();
    }
    
    public String getUsernameText()
    {
        return lblUsername.getText();
    }
    
    public String getPasswordText()
    {
        return lblPassword.getText();
    }

    public void setWebsiteText(String text)
    {
        System.out.println("WEbsite: " + text);
        this.lblWebsite.setText("Website: " + text);
    }
    
    public void setUsernameText(String text)
    {
        this.lblUsername.setText("Username: " + text);
    }
    
    public void setPasswordText(String text)
    {
        this.lblPassword.setText("Password: " + text);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CardView other = (CardView) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.lblWebsite, other.lblWebsite)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.lblUsername, other.lblUsername)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(this.lblPassword, other.lblPassword);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.lblWebsite);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.lblUsername);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.lblPassword);
        return hash;
    }
    
    
}

CardModel
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class CardModel {
    private String website;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public CardModel(String website, String username, String password) {
        this.website = website;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("CardModel{");
        sb.append("website=").append(website);
        sb.append(", username=").append(username);
        sb.append(", password=").append(password);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CardModel other = (CardModel) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.website, other.website)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.username, other.username)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(this.password, other.password);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.website);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.username);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.password);
        return hash;
    }
}

Output

